# School songbook from the 1960s, Zartians

Tags: aliens, story-identification

Somewhere around 1966/1968 in the UK we had a school songbook.

Once a week they dragged out the massive school radio (in a big wooden box on wheels with a speaker mounted on it) and we sang along to some educational radio show.

One of the songs chorus has stuck in my head for all those decades since then, it was about some planet getting invaded by Earthmen and the 'Zartians' were rallying to fight them off.

I only remember a couple of lines, the song began:-

"Calling all Zartians to take a stand, Earthman invaders approach our land..."

The chorus was "Calling all Zartians out, Calling all Zartians out, Calling all Zartians out, Calling all Zartians out"

Somewhere in the middle of the song was the line "our two antenna are extra long"

So clearly the Zartians had antennae.

That's all I recall.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2JqV3ztmfBs  The "two antenna are extra long" is at 1:49.

Comment: https://mudcat.org/thread.cfm?threadid=159349

Comment: Just saying. Just googling "Zartians" would have given you the answer on the first hit. It takes more effort writing this question here than a simple google search.

Comment: I was trying but I was spelling it wrong (Sartiyans) ... It was only when I'd got a long way through writing my question that the memory snapped into place - so I edited my question just prior to posting it! You're correct, I've googled now and it's up right away

Comment: Man, the for-schools shows were great.

Comment: Always post such questions on here, as it's very valuable information cohesion.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Identified in [*this series of posts*](https://mudcat.org/thread.cfm?threadid=159349) as from BBC Schools music broadcast [*Time & Tune*](https://library.efdss.org/cgi-bin/koha/opac-detail.pl?biblionumber=78118) from Spring 1965. The show was broadcast on the radio and featured an accompanying booklet with the various songs and sheet music.

> BATTLE SONG OF THE ZARTIANS
> Tune: [Morning comes early](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AjDLn6dqYHc)
>
> Calling all Zartians to take a stand.
> Earthman invaders approach our land
> Up and attack to make them draw back,
> We are all set and our space-ships manned.
>
> Though we are small we are bold and strong.
> Our two antennae are extra long;
> They can detect each thought as you think it,
> They can transmit every Zartian song.
>
> We are the masters of all the sky.
> Out into space let our rockets fly.
> As you come nearer into our orbit
> Two-legged strangers, prepare to die.

[image]

[image]

[image]

---

You can hear a (not original) version of the song here