# Name of school play from the 1980s about "Zartians"

Tags: story-identification, robots, music, theater-play

In the 1980s at school in UK, we performed a children's musical play that featured traveling to a planet 'zars', full of robot creatures, and my vague memory is of the following song lyrics:

> ... Zartians marching,
> What a cybernating sight to see,
> Pieces of machinery.
> Clashing through the scenery,
> My mates, and me.

I am pretty sure about 'cybernating' and 'Zartians' being in it. It is possible the play also features a jack-and-the-beanstalk theme, and the planet may have been "Zars". But can't find anything on the internet. Anybody recall this or what it's from?

==

### Update

[image: I typed the tune in, as I remember it, in case that rings any bells...]

Comment: Likely a duplicate of [School songbook from the 1960s, Zartians](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/269269/school-songbook-from-the-1960s-zartians)

Comment: @Valorum Those Zartians weren't robots though (were they?), and that was a song rather than a play.

Comment: @ClaraDiazSanchez - I stand by to be astounded if this *isn't* the correct answer

Comment: Thanks - I have seen that question and answer, and that battle song is definitely not the one. These words are not in it. I can even write the music down as I remember it so vividly!